# SQL Statement to pull business with no transaction last 45 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a business table with information about the business and a transactions table with a transactions at different business. I am trying to create a query to give me a list of business names and business were there has not been any transaction recorded in the last 45 days. My current query is using a not in statement looking for business not in the nested query of all businesses with transactions in the last 45 days but keeps timing out.

```
SELECT b.businessid,b.name FROM businesses b where b.businessid not in (SELECT tx.businessid FROM transactions tx
group by businessid
having max(dateAdded) > now()-interval 60 day)
```

Any ideas on how to optimize this to make it run more smoothly?

Comment: Please provide a sample structure and data of your tables, as well as expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to this might be to use exists logic:

```sql
SELECT businessid, name
FROM businesses b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM transactions t
                  WHERE t.businessid = b.businessid AND
                        t.dateAdded > NOW() - INTERVAL 45 DAY);
```

Comment: I think you wanted `>`.

Comment: Also, suggest `INDEX(businessid, dateAdded)`